# add_endRequest doesnt work when i call a file download

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, httpwebrequest, download

Im working with ASP.NET 2008 and I've a two line script on javascript to show a "loading..." message when an update panel works:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(showProgressDialog);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(hideProgressDialog);
```

Its working very good, but when i call a filedownload.aspx that sendme a file, the message appears but never dissapears, like if the endrequest never fired. The file downloads perfectly, i can save it, or open it, anything. Is the "loading..." message the problem, so there is not a problem with the ajax.

Any idea to round up this and close the loading message to let the user working on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve it, i put a set timeout on codebehind ASP that calls a function with a window:location to the url.